# Twilio Dev Phone Plugin Issues during installation

Tags: plugins, twilio, twilio-api, inbound, dev-phone

This is what I am getting while installing the Twilio Virtual Dev Phone Plugin using Twilio CLI:-

```
Installing plugin @twilio-labs/plugin-dev-phone... / info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\twilio-cli\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:78771
    compromised = compromised || function (err) { throw err; };
                                                  ^

Error: Unable to update lock within the stale threshold
    at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\twilio-cli\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:78693:66
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:23) {
  code: 'ECOMPROMISED'
}

Installing plugin @twilio-labs/plugin-dev-phone... failed
    Error: yarn add @twilio-labs/plugin-dev-phone@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\hp\.twilio-cli\yarn.lock
    --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\hp\.twilio-cli\yarn --check-files exited with code 1
```

Any help to address the issue will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: That's strange. Can you please open a issue in the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/twilio-labs/dev-phone)